# "Until now I have been living in the city for a year" or "until now I had been living in the city for a year"?

Tags: present-perfect-progressive, past-perfect-continuous

Could you tell what tense I use after *until now* in the following context: the present perfect continuous or the past perfect continuous?

> I have finally moved to the countryside. Untill now **I have been living** in the city.
>
> I have finally moved to the countryside. Untill now **I had been living** in the city.

Comment: I'd get rid of the "now" and instead say **Until ( this morning/ yesterday / two nights ago...)** You're not living in the city any more.

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to stress the fact that until this very moment I had/have been living in the city. "Until now" is a valid phrase after all.

Comment: *I've **always** liked him until now* is fine (also ***never*** for the opposite). But *I've liked him **for ten years** until now* doesn't work for me. It seems to me you can contrast "time-frame" expressions equivalent to ***no time*** or ***all time*** with a specific point in time *(**until now**)*, but you can't "naturally, easily" contrast the latter with a time period having an explicit duration (but there's no such problem with ***before now***).

Comment: Then it can only be: **I've been living in the city until now** Time expressions normally go at the end, but it's subjective.

Comment: FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica: Thanks for the helpful comment, but what about the sentence? Do I say "I have finally to the countryside. Before now I have been living in the city" or "I have finally moved to the countryside. Untill now I had been living in the city"?

Comment: _Had been_ relates to a given moment in the _past_. 'Until then  I had been...' but 'Until now I have been...'

Comment: @KateBunting - Until now **I had been** because as of now I no longer am.  I don't understand your rational for using **I have been**.  I **have been** living in city for ten years because as of now I still am.

Comment: @EllieK - Well, actually I agree with Mari-Lou's original comment, that if he has already moved he should say 'Until yesterday I had been living...' instead of using _now_. But Dmytro then asked about 'Until this very moment', which requires 'I have been'.